# Typeahead.js with a large database gives Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my project typeahead.js gives error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function

**PHP**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 250;
var duration = 300;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
});
$('input.search').typeahead({
    name: 'companyName',
    remote:'ser_sug.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.bs-example{
font-family: sans-serif;
position: relative;
margin: 50px;
}
.typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 8px;
font-size: 24px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
outline: medium none;
padding: 8px 12px;
width: 396px;
}
.typeahead {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
margin-top: 12px;
padding: 8px 0;
width: 422px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
background-color: #0097CF;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="col-lg-3 cd-row">
            <div class="heading" style="padding:0;margin:0;border:none;">
                <h3 class="advSearchHeading" style="color:#fff;">Search Ceramic</h3>
            </div>
            <form role="form" class="advSearchForm" action="<?php echo SLASHES;?>search/" method="get" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="companyName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Company name" class="search" id="searchid">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="category" class="form-control">
                        <option selected value="">Select Category</option>
                        <?php
                            $categoryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category` where flag = 1 order by `sequence`");
                            while($categoryRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($categoryResult))
                                echo '<option value="'.$categoryRow['cid'].'">'.$categoryRow['cat_name'].'</option>';
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="productSize" id="productSize" class="form-control">
                        <option selected value="">Select Size(CentiMeter)</option>
                        <?php
                            $sizeResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sizes ORDER BY sequence");
                            while($sizeRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sizeResult))
                                echo '<option value="'.$sizeRow['id'].'">'.$sizeRow['inch'].'</option>';
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="location" type="text" value="" placeholder="Addr / city / state / country / pin" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**sur_sug.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','username','pass');
mysql_select_db("database");
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$query=mysql_query("select com_name from company_details where com_name LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $array[] = $row['com_name'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

I have tried to put my `$(document).ready` in a different place, but it's giving the following error:

[image: my error]

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide your folder structure and where is typeahead located?

Answer (score 4):

It have nothing to do with the amount of data but the fact that `public/js/typeahead.js` is not found

Change it to `/js/typeahead.js` and it will properly work

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
  // ...
```

Comment: why is that? i don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is not a problem due to large database.Your script file is not fetching in line

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 250;
var duration = 300;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
});
$('input.search').typeahead({
    name: 'companyName',
    remote:'ser_sug.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10
});
});
</script>
```

To clear that issue you have to give exact path for this script file **typeahead.js** or replace that script line with

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/3.1.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 250;
var duration = 300;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
});
$('input.search').typeahead({
    name: 'companyName',
    remote:'ser_sug.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: then also, same problem.

Comment: right click and take source code chek link is working or not buy clicking it

Answer (score 0):

`Bootstrap Typeahead` is a `Bootstrap plugin`. For this to work it's essential that bootstrap is loaded first. Also make sure `Bootstrap` and `jQuery` is loaded **only once** at the top of any dependent code.

**Any new instances of `Bootstrap` or `jQuery` after loading plugin instance will override the plugin methods.**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/3.1.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
```